# query errors when all data not present

Tags: postgresql-9.2

I have a working query that show success rate of staff.  When I run it in for all staff it works flawlessly.
However, when I insert it as a function within a java based page I get an error:

```
ERROR: division by zero
```

Here is the query and what I think the actual problem is:

```
SELECT st.staff_id, 
  round((count(s.code IN ('10401','10402','10403') OR NULL) * 100.0) / count(*), 1) AS successes
  FROM   notes n
  JOIN   services s  ON s.zzud_service = n.zrud_service
  WHERE n.zrud_staff = ? AND n.date_service >= DATE '07/01/2013' 
    AND n.date_service <= CURRENT_DATE 
    AND  s.code IN ('10401','10402','10403','10405')
  GROUP  BY st.staff_id
```

The 10401, 10402, 10403 codes reflect successful discharges.
The 10405 reflect unsuccessful discharges.

If a staff has no notes (new staff for example) I get the division by zero error.

So I believe if a staff does not have at least one entry for one of the codes, it will error.  This prevents them from logging in.

I read of an operator called NULLIF() that would prevent this, but I do not have any idea how to insert it, and, if this will actually work.

Can anyone comment?

Comment: Irrelevant to the question: The `OR NULL` should be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
count(*)
```

should become

```
coalesce(count(*), 1)
```

for the simplest case. The denominator doesn't actually matter because 0/anything is always zero.

---

Also:

```
s.code IN ('10401','10402','10403') OR NULL
```

is nonsense. `count(x OR NULL)` is exactly the same as `count(x)`. `NULL` is false in boolean context, `x OR NULL` is the same as just saying `x`. So just write:

```
s.code IN ('10401','10402','10403')
```

If what you're actually trying to say is "count rows that are either one of the listed values or are null" then you need a `coalesce`. You can't just use `IN (..., NULL)` since `x IN (..., NULL)` is always either true or `NULL`, since `x IN (...)` is equivalent to `x = ANY (...)` and `x = NULL` is `NULL`. So you must write:

```
s.code IN ('10401','10402','10403') OR s.code IS NULL
```

Comment: When I add coalesce, it errors at the "AS" statement, so I figured I needed another ending paran :   round((count(s.code IN ('10401','10402','10403') OR NULL) * 100.0) / count(*), 1) AS successes

Comment: When I add coalesce, it errors at the "AS" statement, so I figured I needed another ending paran :   round((count(s.code IN ('10401','10402','10403') OR NULL) * 100.0) / count(*), 1) AS successes
This fixes the "AS" error, but the same result occurs = if there is not at least one of the codes present, the query fails. I tried omitting the "OR NULL" and again, if there is not at least one of the codes present it fails.

Comment: @Detox Your comments appear to completely ignore the contents of this answer. Where's the `coalesce` around the `count` to protect against a `null` denominator? The whole statement suggests you need to study how `NULL` works in SQL, it doesn't behave consistently or how you probably think it does.

Comment: Please forgive me if I have disrespected you!  My abbreviated responses did not reflect what actually happened. When I use the line SELECT st.staff_id, 
  round((count(s.code IN ('10401','10402','10403') OR NULL) * 100.0) / count(*), 1) AS successes as it stands, it results in success rate of 50% for a staff who logs in with one service of 10401 and 10405 this gives a code from both sides.  If a staff logs in with a single code of 10405, it shows success rate of 0%.  If a staff logs in with none of the codes present, it errors.  I took to heart your comment and read a lot on your suggestion

Comment: If I remove the "OR NULL" from the end of this -SELECT st.staff_id, 
  round((count(s.code IN ('10401','10402','10403') OR NULL) * 100.0) it skews the result to 100% or nothing.  I then ammended it to SELECT st.staff_id, 
  round((count(s.code IN ('10401','10402','10403') OR NULL) * 100.0) / NULLIF (count(*),0)) AS success and that gives accurate percentage if at least one code is present and a blank % if there are no codes present. I will experiment a few more times to make sure it is not a cruel cosmic joke that it is working and will let you know. Thanks for all your help

Comment: I verified in the DB that a staff had none of these codes, logged in and show blank%.  I added a code 10405 (unsuccessful) relogged in and shows 0%.  I added a 10402 relogged in and shows 50%.  So I believe this is the solution. Your comments suggest a better way,and I would really like to make it work the cleanest way possible.  However, bullet comments will be frustrating for you and me as my knowledge is very new and limited.  I will keep reading.  Please let me see how you would "retool" the query so I can learn a better way if mine is kludgy.  Thanks again!

Comment: @Detox It might be worth posting an SQLFiddle (http://sqlfiddle.com) with a skeleton of sample data that demonstrates your query and the different cases it needs to handle (zero rows, one row, two rows, etc). If you post a link here I'll be happy to take a look. It's much harder working with fragments of queries on unseen data, too much chance of subtle issues slipping in. As for "disrespect" - sorry, text doesn't have much in the way of tone, I'm not bothered and even if I was it'd be my problem.